# generate date range between min and max dates Athena presto SQL sequence error

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm attempting to generate a series of dates in Presto SQL (Athena) using `unnest` and `sequence` something similair to `generate_series` in postgres.

my table looks like

```
job_name | run_date     
A        | '2021-08-21'
A        | '2021-08-25' 
B        | '2021-08-07' 
B        | '2021-08-24' 


SELECT d.job_name, d.run_date
FROM (
     VALUES
        ('A', '2021-08-21'), ('A', '2021-08-25'),
        ('B', '2021-08-07'), ('B', '2021-08-24')
         ) d(job_name, run_date)
```

---

I'm aiming for an output as follows

```
job_name |   run_date
       A | 2021-08-21
       A | 2021-08-22
       A | 2021-08-23
       A | 2021-08-24
       A | 2021-08-25
       B | 2021-08-07
       B | 2021-08-08
       B | 2021-08-09
       B | 2021-08-10
       B | 2021-08-11
       B | 2021-08-12
       B | 2021-08-13
       B | 2021-08-14
       B | 2021-08-15
       B | 2021-08-16
       B | 2021-08-17
       B | 2021-08-18
       B | 2021-08-19
       B | 2021-08-20
       B | 2021-08-21
       B | 2021-08-22
       B | 2021-08-23
       B | 2021-08-24
```

---

I've attempted to use the following query to achieve this - however I get an error when trying to unnest my date sequence

```
SELECT t.job_name, d.dte
FROM (SELECT job_name
        ,    min(run_date) as mind
        ,    max(run_date) as maxd
        ,    SEQUENCE(min(run_date), max(run_date)) as date_arr
     FROM job_log_table t
     GROUP BY job_name
  )  jd
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(jd.date_arr) d(dte)
LEFT JOIN job_log_table t 
    ON t.job_name = jd.job_name
    AND t.latest_date = d.dte;
```

which yields the following error :

```
[HY000][100071] [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. [ErrorCategory:USER_ERROR, ErrorCode:SYNTAX_ERROR], Detail:SYNTAX_ERROR: line 5:14: Unexpected parameters (date, date) for function sequence. Expected: sequence(bigint, bigint, bigint) , sequence(bigint, bigint) , sequence(timestamp, timestamp, interval day to second) , sequence(timestamp, timestamp, interval year to month)
```

Is this a limitation of Athena's flavour of Presto SQL or have I made a school boy error somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide `interval` to generate date sequence (in this case `interval '1' day`):

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    ( VALUES      
        ('A', DATE '2021-08-21'), ('A', DATE '2021-08-25'),
        ('B', DATE '2021-08-07'), ('B', DATE '2021-08-24')
    ) AS d (job_name, run_date)
) 

select job_name, sequence(min(run_date), max(run_date), interval '1' day) seq
from dataset
group by job_name
```

Output:

| job_name | seq |
| --- | --- |
| A | [2021-08-21 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-22 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-23 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-24 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-25 00:00:00.000] |
| B | [2021-08-07 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-08 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-09 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-10 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-11 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-12 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-13 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-14 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-15 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-16 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-17 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-18 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-19 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-20 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-21 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-22 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-23 00:00:00.000, 2021-08-24 00:00:00.000] |

Comment: @Umar.H glad if it helped!