# UNNEST an interval of all dates without grouping by column

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I want to UNNEST an interval of all dates within the min and max of a date column without grouping by any other column.

Building off the [answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68940499/1884171), I can get close, but instead of getting the date range grouped by each `job_name`, I want to generate the total date range across all `job_name` values. So each `job_name` should be exploded to have 3-rows for 2021-08-20 through 2021-08-22.

```
WITH 
    dataset AS (
      SELECT * 
      FROM 
        ( VALUES      
            ('A', DATE '2021-08-21'), ('A', DATE '2021-08-22'),
            ('B', DATE '2021-08-20'), ('B', DATE '2021-08-21')
        ) AS d (job_name, run_date)),
    
    nested_dates AS (
        select job_name, sequence(min(run_date), max(run_date), interval '1' day) seq
        from dataset
        group by job_name)

SELECT job_name, dates
FROM nested_dates
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(seq) AS t(dates)
```

Current output:

```
#   job_name    dates
1   A   2021-08-21 00:00:00.000
2   A   2021-08-22 00:00:00.000
3   B   2021-08-20 00:00:00.000
4   B   2021-08-21 00:00:00.000
```

Desired output:

```
#   job_name    dates
1   A   2021-08-20 00:00:00.000
2   A   2021-08-21 00:00:00.000
3   A   2021-08-22 00:00:00.000
3   B   2021-08-20 00:00:00.000
4   B   2021-08-21 00:00:00.000
5   B   2021-08-22 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be using windows functions and distinct select:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(job_name, run_date) AS (
VALUES ('A', DATE '2021-08-21'), 
    ('A', DATE '2021-08-22'), 
    ('B', DATE '2021-08-20'), 
    ('B', DATE '2021-08-21')), 

nested_dates AS (
    select distinct job_name, max (run_date) over() max_run_date, min (run_date) over() min_run_date
    from dataset)

-- query 
select job_name, dates
from nested_dates,
unnest (sequence(min_run_date, max_run_date, interval '1' day)) AS t(dates)
order by job_name, dates;
```

Output:

| job_name | dates |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-08-20 |
| A | 2021-08-21 |
| A | 2021-08-22 |
| B | 2021-08-20 |
| B | 2021-08-21 |
| B | 2021-08-22 |